# Verificar Login e Senha AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho a seguinte função para login:

```
function login(username, password, callback) {
        var myResponse;
        var systemUser;

        Users.getByLogin(username)
        .then(function (response) {
            systemUser = response.data;
        });

        // Linha testada
        console.log("Senha: " + systemUser.password);
        console.log("Senha informada: " + password);

        if (typeof systemUser == "undefined") {
            myResponse = { success: false, message: "Usuário inexistente!" };
        } else if (password == systemUser.password) {
            myResponse = { success: true, user: systemUser };
        } else {
            myResponse = { success: false, message: "Usuário ou senha incorretos!" };
        }

        callback(myResponse);
    }
```

Normalmente ocorre o erro `TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined`.

Se eu declarar a variável `systemUser` de fora da função , observando a linha do comentário `Linha testada`, o valor dá undefined na primeira vez que chamo o método, mas na segunda vez passa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o método `Users.getByLogin()` é assíncrono.

Seu erro ocorre porque no momento em que a linha `console.log("Senha: " + systemUser.password);` é executada o retorno de `getByLogin` ainda não ocorreu; `systemUser` é ainda uma variável nula.

Uma vez que o resultado seja retornado, a função especificada em `.then()` será executada. Modifique o seu código como sugerido abaixo:

```
function login(username, password, callback) {
    var myResponse;
    var systemUser;

    Users.getByLogin(username)
    .then(function (response) {
        systemUser = response.data;

        // Linha testada
        console.log("Senha: " + systemUser.password);
        console.log("Senha informada: " + password);

        if (typeof systemUser == "undefined") {
            myResponse = { success: false, message: "Usuário inexistente!" };
        } else if (password == systemUser.password) {
            myResponse = { success: true, user: systemUser };
        } else {
            myResponse = { success: false, message: "Usuário ou senha incorretos!" };
        }

        callback(myResponse);
    });
}
```

Comment: Esqueci mesmo desta questão da sincronização, realmente as consultas AJAX são assíncronas! Obrigado!